# How can I pass my csv file as Form Data using REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I'm having a hard time on encoding my uploaded CSV file to Form Data, This is the idea I came up with to be able to pass the actual file to be processed on the backend using post method of my API. But unfortunately, I'm getting an error **"TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'."**. I am new to programming so I hope you understand. Thank you!

Here is some snippet of what I've done:

**uploadedProducts** contains the csv file I uploaded.

```
        upload() {
          let data = new FormData(self.uploadedProducts);
          
          axios.post(`${api}/mc/upload/specifications`, {
              data,
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
              }
          })
          .then((result) => {
              let responseData = result.data
              alert("Uploaded successfully!")     
          })
          .catch((error) => {
              self.showErrorMessage(error.message);
          })
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you got all of the other things right, but I know for sure that you need to change the content-type:   `axios.post(`${api}/mc/upload/specifications`, { data, headers: { 'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data' } })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var formData = new FormData(form)
```

The `form` must be an HTML  element. Please read [FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData). From your errors I guess your `self.uploadedProducts` is not a form element.

The alternative is use `append` method. Please read [FormData.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append).

So your code should be something like:

```js
upload() {
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('fieldName', self.uploadedProducts);
    ...
    // you can omit multipart/form-data header
    axios.post(`${api}/mc/upload/specifications`, data)
    ...
}
```